# Argument 1 passed to Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, forms, controller

I want to register on my site with an invitation code, so I added in my controller If statement for checking the activation code

```
 protected function create (array $data)
    {
        if ($data['activation_code'] === 'mypassword123') {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }
            return redirect('/register')->with('message', 'De activatiecode is onjuist');
        }

}
```

And when I submit the registration I get this error

**Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\Suppliers\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35**

So I don't know where the problem is, please help

Comment: You're returning the result of User::create() that is the User object. You need to return a element to render or a redirect page.

Comment: You're returning a response. But laravel want's you to return a Model that extends Authenticable (User). Can we please see the comments above the method?

Comment: @Ezrab_ You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment said `protected function create (array $data)` is not responsible for redirecting to a different page and the logic, I think, should not be there either.

you can either overwrite the `register` method from `trait RegistersUsers` or create a middleware.

1. overriding `register` method, in `RegisterController` add the logic here.

```php
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        if ('mypassword123' !== $request->input('activation_code')) {
            return redirect('/register')->with('message', 'De activatiecode is onjuist');
        }

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

2. Middleware

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckCode
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ('mypassword123' !== $request->input('activation_code')) {
            return redirect('/register')->with('message', 'De activatiecode is onjuist');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then add it when you need it.

```php
use App\Http\Middleware\CheckAge;

Route::get('someroutes', function () {
    //some code
})->middleware(CheckCode::class);
```

Hope this helps.